# Two Models or One View?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use two models in one View. Here is my code:

```
public class Users {
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string adSoyad { get; set; }
   public string email { get; set; }
   public int puan { get; set; }
}
public class admin {
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
}

public class mainmodel {
   public Users Users { get; set; }
   public admin admin { get; set; }
}
```

I can use it to delete, edit, and create views. But I get errors in my index view:

```
@model IEnumerable<donemProje.Models.mainmodel>
```

What can I do?

Edit--
i try  this in index  view

```
@model donemProje.Models.mainmodel


@foreach (var item in Model.Users)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.adSoyad)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
```

and  get  this error

Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'donemProje.Models.Users' because 'donemProje.Models.Users' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

int this line

Line 34: `@foreach (var item in Model.Users)`

Comment: Users class have can have multiple records ? and admin class also can have multiple or only a record ?

Answer (score 0):

Your model in the view should be @model mainmodel

Answer (score 0):

`@model IEnumrable` or you tried `@model IeEnumrable<mainmodel>` ? if you tried `@model IEnumrable<mainmodel>` than mainmodel have list of users and admin in it. but what i understand from your question i think the below words will help you.

You can try `@model mainmodel` and you can iterate through mainmodel using foreach loop.

```
foreach(var user in Model.Users)
{
  // you code goes here..
}
```

and same thing for the admin if want to iterate through admin. else just use `@Model.Admin.id`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use two models in one view, you should use ViewModels (A class which consists of other classes which are used in view)